# Where can I find the include files for MySQL on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, lamp

Where can I find the include files for MySQL on Linux? I looked in /usr/include/mysql according to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installation-layouts.html) but they are not there. My apache web server works fine with MySQL 5.1 up and running with PHP 5, but I can't find where the includes directory is!!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what distro are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 8.10 is the distro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ mysql_config --include
```

On my system, this prints `-I/usr/include/mysql`

If the directory revealed by `mysql_config` doesn't have the right include files, your installation may have been partial or may have been altered after the fact.

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-config.html):

> mysql_config provides you with useful information for compiling your MySQL client and connecting it to MySQL....
>
> **--include**
>
> Compiler options to find MySQL include files.

Comment: not work for me, there is no mysql_config binary with mysql 5.5.35. :(

Comment: @Jean-Luc Barat, perhaps you are missing the "devel" files.  Others on even older 5.5 versions [don't have that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10521787/132382).

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on the Linux distro you are using.  Most binary distros ship the headers separate from the application itself, often in a -devel package.

For instance, on my Fedora 12 machine the `mysql-devel` package has the following description:

> MySQL is a multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database server. This package contains the libraries and header files that are needed for developing MySQL client applications.

On Fedora, CentOS, or RHEL,you can install this package by `yum install mysql-devel` as root.  Debian and Ubuntu systems will have a similar package name and command for apt.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me by installing libmysqlclient-dev in ubuntu-14.04.

Then I could find files in /usr/include/mysql